# Implementation of WS in latest play framework 2.5.10 in scala

Tags: scala, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.5

I want to hit `GET` api request using latest play framework in scala. I think use case for ws service is changed in Play 2.5+. I am using following code.

```
class  ApiResult @Inject() (ws: WSClient)  {

  def getApiResult(param1: String, param2: String)= {

    var response = ws.url(s"ip-address/getApiResult/${param1}/${param2}").withRequestTimeout(5000.millis).get()
    var i = 0
    while(i < 2 && !response.isCompleted ){
     response = ws.url(s"ip-address/getSmsCredit/${param1}/${param2}").withRequestTimeout(5000.millis).get()
     i += 1
    }

    val result = response.onComplete {
     case Success(jsonOutput) => 
      val x= (jsonOutput.json \ "x").getOrElse(Json.toJson(-1)).as[Double]
      val y= (jsonOutput.json \ "y").getOrElse(Json.toJson(-1)).as[Double]
      val z= (jsonOutput.json \ "z").getOrElse(Json.toJson(-1)).as[Double]

      SomeCaseClass(x, y, z)
    case _ => 
     Logger.info("Error")
     SomeCaseClass(0.00, 0.00, 0.00)
   }
   result
 }
}
```

I want to basically return SomeCaseClass , when I will call getApiResult in some other function. Also, how do I call this function there, since this function using param WSClient

Answer (score 0):

There are so many wrong things in your code, but let's assume you want a Future to return from this method you should do something like this:

```
def getApiResult(param1: String, param2: String): Future[SomeCaseClass] = {
   ws.url(s"ip-address/getApiResult/${param1}/${param2}")
     .withRequestTimeout(5000.millis).get()
     .flatMap(_ =>  //Will get here after the first request finished
        ws.url(s"ip-address/getSmsCredit/${param1}/${param2}")
        .withRequestTimeout(5000.millis).get()
        .map(_.body.validate[SomeCaseClass]
              .asOpt
              .getOrElse(SomeCaseClass(0.00, 0.00, 0.00)))
  )
}
```

You will need to implement an implicit reader:

```
object SomeCaseClass{
  implicit val reads: Reads[SomeCaseClass] = (
    (__ \ "x").read[Double] and
      (__ \ "y").read[Double] and
      (__ \ "z").read[Double]
    )(SomeCaseClass.apply _)
}
```

If you want the actual SomeCaseClass, you whould do Await on getApiResult.

Comment: Hey Tomer, Thanks for your answer, Actually I was making  more than 1 request just in case 1st request timeout. Earlier I was having problem with initialising WSClient, So later I injected WSClient in my main Controller itself, than initialising this class using that WSClient. Than, it worked perfectly fine.